# NVD3 and D3.js - MultiBarChart (stacked and grouped) with line chart

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

i'm currently working with d3.js and with the nvd3 library, i need a chart that has multiple bars that can be stacked and grouped like this example http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html plus a line chart like the following example http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html

So what I need exactly is a MultiBarChart with a line chart , can anyone show me an example somewhere. Thanks

Comment: You can use [this](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html) and make sure in the data you pass into the chart you mention `"bar": true`. In the code check `line 33` and beyond for the JSON data structure.

Comment: Yea but it there is no option to stack and group the bars.

Comment: This isn't implemented in NVD3.

Comment: Is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Use d3, make group stacked bar, then make line chart with same y domain.